# Excel VBA: Animating Visibility of a Range w/ RowHeight loop

Tags: vba, excel

I am interested in showing/hiding several ranges on my workbook. Normally I would just test whether or not the range is already hidden and set the following to either true or false `rng.EntireRow.Hidden`.

I would like to make my project feel more like an app (yes I know excel probably isn't the best place to go with it, but attention to small details like this is my kind of thing). The following is an example of what I am trying to do. It works, especially on a clean worksheet/workbook. The problem is that on the workbook in which I am trying to use it, there is already a ton of data/formatting/shapes on the worksheet. This is causing "skips" in the smoothness of the loop. I have tried different step by's, but nothing really seems to solve it. The `DoEvents` was necessary in order to see any animation at all.

If anyone has an idea on how to make this work, or if it's at all possible, that would be great. Thanks!

```
Sub testView()

Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Integer

With ActiveSheet
    Set rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(20, 1))
    If rng.EntireRow.Hidden = True Then
        For i = 1 To 15 Step 1
            rng.EntireRow.RowHeight = i
            DoEvents
        Next i
    Else
        For i = 14 To 0 Step -1
            rng.EntireRow.RowHeight = i
            DoEvents
        Next i
    End If

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: `The problem is that on the workbook in which I am trying to use it, there is already a ton of data/formatting/shapes on the worksheet. This is causing "skips" in the smoothness of the loop.` What exactly causes skips in what smoothness, be more specific and provide examples.  `I have tried different step by's, but nothing really seems to solve it.` Be specific, what have you tried, and why did that not work?

Comment: Things that I've tried.. looping through each row in the range, modifying the height by a factor (I've tried multiple factors). This method usually results in a much slower result (and also less smooth). I did already note some of the things I specifically did.. including changing the "Step by". Perhaps that was lost in my message. I have replaced the DoEvents in the code with the code provided by John below, it actually seemed to cause the animation to be more smooth. I will further test his method.

Answer (score 2):

I do a lot of animations in Excel for pedagogical reasons (mostly animations of charts). I sometimes use variations of the following sub:

```
Sub Pause(delay As Double)
    Dim start As Double
    start = Timer
    Do While Timer < start + delay
        DoEvents
    Loop
End Sub
```

Then in the main code, have something like `Pause 0.10` after (or instead of) where you currently have `DoEvents`. Low tech, but it sometimes helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer John. Interesting.. I did replace the my DoEvents with your loop, while passing .1 as suggested. It actually seemed to smooth out the transition by the smallest of margins, so it is a step in the right direction. Will try and play around with it a bit more to confirm/improve results. Thanks